# Images off-center in BXSlider

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I'm working on creating a portfolio site, but I keep having trouble with a carousel. I decided to try bxslider because I like the styling, but it's been bothering me for a week now as to how to get the images to center in the viewport.

I've managed to get the slider up and running, but my images keep showing up as off-center, as though there's some conflicting CSS somewhere. The images are 800px by 300px - I can set the width of the box to 800px by setting `slideWidth:800`, but that doesn't fix the issue. You can see that the captions are cut off - the image is being shifted down and right.

See a [test page](http://filetanic.com/stackoverflow/) - this is using an unmodified copy of bxslider and no additional CSS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated -- I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm still newish to this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're off center because your images are too large, and they're left-aligned so they extend out of their parents to the right. Describe what layout you're after and I can help further. Here's a guess:

```
.bx-wrapper img {
    width: 720px;
    height: 230px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
    width: 720px;
}
```

You could also do this:

```
.bx-wrapper {
    width: 880px;
}
.bx-viewport {
    height: 340px;
}
```

Update based on your comments:

```
.bx-viewport ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - I tried setting the following:

`.bx-wrapper img {
 display: block;
 width: 810px;
        height: 310px;
}`

as well as the caption width. This adjusts the viewport size, but the [image is still shifted](http://www.filetanic.com/stackoverflow), even though the box is technically larger than the image (the image is 800x300).

The style I'm going after is the one on the [bxslider home page](http://bxslider.com), where there are only a few pixels on all sides of the image. As long as I can get it to not shift/cut off, I should be able to adjust it as necessary.

Comment: See my updated answer. You apparently have some unrelated list styles causing your troubles.